# How to get every objects one at a time Django

Tags: django

Here is my def :

```
@register.inclusion_tag('menu/home.html')
def show_menu():
    buttonname = Button.objects.all()
    return {'button': buttonname}
```

Here is my home.html :

```
{% for buttons in button %}
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">
        <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{ button }}
        </button>
    </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that it displays the queryset of all the buttons everytime. How do I display one object at a time ?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388159/django-templates-display-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting button list with 'button' variable name from the definition. I advise you to rename it 'buttons'( plural ) as name.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('menu/home.html')
def show_menu():
    buttons = Button.objects.all()
    return {'buttons': buttons}
```

so in the for loop in the template you should do

```
{% for button in buttons %}
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">
     <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{ button }}
    </button>
   </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: buttons in button is working fine and what you gave me is not working, that's not the problem tho

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Do you know how to call the id AND the name tho ? Sorry to bother you x)

Comment: {{ button.id }}  or {{ button.name }}

Comment: Thanks you dude :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but why can't I do "button.dirurl" or "button.co" ? I can do button.id tho. button.dirurl and .co are both str.